# States undefined in unit testing

Tags: reactjs, enzyme

I'm trying a very simple shallow test for a component:

```
it('renders without crashing', () => {

shallow(<SampleComponent />);
});
```

In my sample component, I did a setState :

```
 this.setState({myCurrentState: "InSample"});
```

Now somewhere in my return, I used that to output an element, say:

```
return ( <h1> this.state.myCurrentState </h1>)
```

When I try the above test, I get

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined.
```

I know that I can pass in props to shallow, but I can't seem to figure how to do it with states. Is there a better way of doing it? Sorry I'm new to React and unit testing. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'enzyme';

import SampleComponent from './SampleComponent';

describe('< SampleComponent />', () => {
  it('should render', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent name="Example" />);
    expect(wrapper).toHaveLength(1);
  });
   describe('check props', () => {
     const wrapper = shallow(<SampleComponent name="Example" />);
     console.log(warpper.instance().props); // you should see name='Example'
 });
});
```

Please check out this link http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/

You can't call the state like this `return ( <h1> this.state.myCurrentState </h1>)` you have to put it into **{ }** like

```
return ( <h1> {this.state.myCurrentState} </h1>)
```

If you still having a troubles watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5XTnNBotqs)

Comment: I get ReferenceError: MyComponent is not defined, my this.state.myCurrentState has { } originally, that was just a typo

Comment: Where are you importing `expect` from?

Comment: inside my test.js along with enzyme

Comment: @JRebo Let me know if it's fixed your problem

Comment: Thanks a lot! Definitely gonna read through the link too @Liamm12

Comment: Hey, you are importing render and applying shallow.

Answer (score 0):

```js
Use Something like this:

class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      myCurrentState: null
    };
    
    // somewhere in your code in one of the method
    
    this.setState({myCurrentState: "InSample"});
    
    render() {
      return (
        <h1>{this.state.myCurrentState}</h1>
      );
    }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I have in my SomeComponent, my problem is when I do unit testing. Doing it('renders without crashing', () => {

shallow(<SampleComponent />);
}); gives me an error.